# c# - autofill program, how can i autofill select tag in browser? select box?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, web

I recently want to make auto-typing, auto-fill Explorer browser, using Windows program with c#.net programming.

I can auto type in text type but I cannot autotype the 'select tag'.

I searched and I think I can use 'setAttribute("value","selectIndexnumber")'
but, I didn't work well. Explorer does not perceive the 'change' state.

So first, I used IHTMLElement3.FireEvent("onchange",null); to invoke 'onchange'

but it didn't work, too.

and Secondely, I used SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");

but it didn't work, too.

how can I autofill the 'select tag' well with no problem like user change the select tag?

please help me. thanks in advance!

below is the code that i wrote.

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer browser;            

        SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
        string filename;
        MessageBox.Show("shellWindows number is " + shellWindows.Count);
        foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
        {
            filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower();
            if ((filename == "iexplore"))
            {
                browser = ie;

                String myDocURL = browser.Document.url;
                MessageBox.Show("this is url" + myDocURL);
                if (myDocURL == "https://hankooktire.recruiter.co.kr/app/applicant/modifyResume")
                {
                    IHTMLDocument3 ihtml3doc = (IHTMLDocument3)browser.Document;
                    IHTMLElement3 ihtml3ele = ihtml3doc.getElementById("jobnoticeSn") as IHTMLElement3;
                    IHTMLElement ihtmlele = ihtml3doc.getElementById("jobnoticeSn");
                    ihtmlele.setAttribute("value", "4");
                    IHTMLSelectElement selEle = ihtml3ele as IHTMLSelectElement;


                    //selEle.selectedIndex=4;


                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                    ihtml3ele.FireEvent("onchange", null);
                    //SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                    ihtml3doc.getElementById("jobnoticeSn").children(4).setAttribute("selected", "true");
                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                    //ihtml3doc.getElementById("jobnoticeSn").children(4).setAttribute("checked", "true");
                    //ihtml3doc.getElementById("jobnoticeSn").children(4).setAttribute("selectedIndex", "true");


                    //ihtml3doc.getElementById("jobnoticeSn").setAttribute("selected", "selected");

                    //ihtml3doc.getElementById("jobnoticeSn").setAttribute("value", "8130");
                    ihtml3doc.getElementById("name").setAttribute("value", "김준혁");
                    ihtml3doc.getElementById("birthday").setAttribute("value", "1989-11-18");
                    ihtml3doc.getElementById("man").setAttribute("checked", "true");
                    ihtml3doc.getElementById("email").setAttribute("value", "jjunest@gmail.com");
                    ihtml3doc.getElementById("password").setAttribute("value", "emfla248248");


                    //ihtml3doc.getElementById("password").scrollIntoView();


                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does ' but i cannot autotype the 'select tag'' mean?

Comment: Think you need to set the [Selected attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) of the desired `Option` element *within* the `Select` tag.

Comment: To LeiYang. i can autofill <selected> tags with values, and it looks like it was actually clicked. but when I click the 'submit' button on browser, it is said that '<selectd>tag don't have any values'! and I can not submit the form in the browser. I think it is because of not calling 'onchage' state.

Comment: Oh! I checked this reference and it didn't work ! how can i solve this problem..... (1)https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/31217de9-6cba-462c-88db-685656abcbb6/onchange-event-for-select-element-using-fireevent-in-vbnet?forum=ieextensiondevelopment

Comment: how about use http post instead of webbrowser?

Comment: To LeiYang. No.. not using http post..  i just need to set the value of the select tag and that's it. because user should check if the auto-program works fine. thanks. plz help me ..

Comment: consider selenium?